# How to extract files from a split 7zip archive ended by .001 and .002?

Tags: extract, 7zip, decompression

I have two files  data.7z.001 and data.7z.002.
l tried to extract them using  :

```
7z e asdf data.7z.001
```

l got this error

```
   7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
    p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
Error:
there is no such archive
```

and

```
7z x /home/Desktop/data.7z.001 -tufd.split -o/home/Desktop/
```

error :

```
Error:
Unsupported archive type
```

and

```
7z x /home/Desktop/data.7z.001 -tiso.split -o/home/Desktop/
```

error :

```
Error:
Unsupported archive type
```

Comment: remove the space after `-o`

Comment: you mean 7z x data.7z.001 -tufd.split -o/home/Desktop/  ?  error is Unsupported archive type

Comment: What's the output of `file data.7z.*`?

Comment: data.7z.001 : 7-zip archive data, version 0.4
data.7z.002 :  data

Answer (score 8):

```
7z x data.7z.001
```

7z like that will find the others automatically (002 003 and so on)

Comment: it works perfectly  for  data.7z.001 but  for data.7z.002 Error: Can not open file as archive

Comment: Can you check the size of the files please? It sounds like it wasn't completed right the creating of the zip files.

Comment: 104.9 mo for data.7z.001 and 69.7 mo for data.7z.002

Comment: Can you give it a try with:

Comment: Can you give it a try with:
7zr x data.7z.001

With the 'r' with 7z. Found this option in a few sites but not sure if that will work.

Comment: for data.7z.001 it's ok but for data.7z.002  Error: Can not open file as archive

Comment: such that the output : data.7z.001 : 7-zip archive data, version 0.4
data.7z.002 :  data

Answer (score 5):

I continued getting an "Unknown format" error until doing the following:

```
7z e file.7z.001 -tsplit
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Option `x` supports full path. Option `e` for only names (as in your example). Option `t` is for testing.

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: For SEO’s sake : I got *Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive ERRORS:
Unexpected end of archive Can't open as archive: 1* without `-tsplit`, worked like a charm with `-tsplit`.